# Periodicity for Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-process, state-space-models

[image]

I don't understand why the only state with period > 1 is 1
Let's take state 2 for example, what's the period for state 2?
Another question is, does an absorbing state(state 4 in this example) only have period of 1?

Comment: Good question.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48838.  Perhaps you should consult the source of your image to find out precisely what its definition of "period" is.  Perhaps it's non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

An absorbing state has a preriod of **1**, yes. Because there is a *loop* on himself. It's true only if it's not in an absorbing class.

But states **1**,**2**,**3**,**5** and **6** are in the same class of communication (*you can go to an other state of the class and come back if you want*) so they have the same period. which is **3**.

If you gave us the source maybe there is some explanation.

[Is this Markov chain irreducible?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77844/is-this-markov-chain-irreducible)

You can read that, it can be helpful.

Comment: (+1) It might help to explain why state 1, which can be returned to only in 3 steps, has the same period as e.g. 2, which can be returned to in either 3 or 6 steps.